# JavaScript Pub/Sub - Message Priorities

Tags: javascript

More of a discussion than a question:

I've been reading an article titled 'Patterns For Large-Scale JavaScript Application Architecture' and so far it's been quite an eye opener.

The author of this article advocates the use of a pub/sub architecture with the use of a mediator/controller. There aren't any real-world examples given but on the actual slide show (http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqcon-largescalejs-2012/) he advocates using 'Amplify.js'.

Like many other pub/sub implementations Amplify supports message priorities. My understanding is that with a mediator in place the need for prioritising messages is diminished because the mediator takes control of what happens when and where. Is this a valid point?

Message priorities scare me because when the application grows (and varies) you could end up with a heap of modules all with different priorities set on their subscriptions and no real control over what's going on. Is this a valid concern or simply a misunderstanding of how they should actually be used?

Comment: No responses for this question. I think perhaps my question is too specific. In any case I just wanted to share what I've learned and the understanding I've come to. In short, I would not advocate the use of priorities to manage complex communications between components. Instead use them like channels to govern the TYPE of communication (i.e. debug channel is 1, normal channel is 2) so debug components always get the messages first.

Comment: Your question and your comment reflect my own feelings. We are currently investigating which pub/sub library to use and I feel that having priorities will lead to a new form of invisible coupling. Your idea of using the priorities as well defined channels is probably the only safe use of the concept.

Comment: As a side note, if you are doing Pub/Sub in JavaScript, might I suggest looking into SignalR if you haven't already. I used it in my last project and it works great. It might even have the priority stuff built in there for you. I know your question is closer to a theoretical conversation and I would lean towards defined channels myself as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would caution against using any complicated version of pub/sub. Instead of thinking in terms of priorities, think in terms of channels, and assume that all channels are handled independently of each other, and none of them have "priority".

Another caution: Don't use your module names as channel names or namespaces. If you do, you may as well be giving other modules a direct reference to your module and calling methods directly. The whole point is that your modules don't know about each other, and don't communicate directly.

One other tip: Don't tell other modules what to do. Instead, report events that have happened inside the module sending the message. That subtle shift in thinking is key to keeping modules decoupled.

Comment: I agree with Eric here. Putting a priority on a subscription seems (to me) to suggest that one module will need to have enough knowledge of another to determine whether or not it actually should have priority; which in turn would suggest that the modules aren't very loosely coupled. The way I've always done it is to keep it simple. Publish that an event has occurred and simply let all of the modules that have subscribed do what they need to do.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this usage for pub/sub priorities helpful, based on the good idea of using them as 'channels' as suggested on this question.

**Priorities for subscriptions, where 1 is highest and 5 is lowest:**

1. Debug messages
2. Subscriptions with any DOM layout changes involved, that affects the size or position of elements.
3. Subscriptions with just style DOM changes involved, which do not affect layout.
4. Subscriptions which read layout or style in the DOM.
5. Subscriptions with no DOM touching (pure JS).

This should hopefully prevent as much [layout thrashing](http://www.kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/) as possible.

*Sorry to reply to an old post, but it's first page in google for "pub sub priority" and there isn't much out there on this.*